# Can anyone please post small example of Dockerfile for web app in python in detailed steps?

Tags: python-3.x, docker

Facing following error when I do:

```sh
docker build -t web_app .
```

My web_app structure is :

```
web-app
├── Dockerfile
└── src
    └── server.py
    └── requirements.txt
```

ERROR: No matching distribution found for aiohttp (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6

# Create app directory 
WORKDIR /app

# Install app dependencies 
COPY src/requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Bundle app source 
COPY src /app

EXPOSE 8080 
CMD [ "python", "server.py" ]
```

Please help.

Comment: Would you post the Dockerfile? Seems that the base python version is mismatching.

Comment: can you post the content of `requirements.txt` as well?

Comment: requirements.txt contains just aiohttp and in server.py just running web app using aiohhtp's web.(web.Application())

Comment: ok, but is it requiring a special version of aiohttp?

Comment: No, not like this, as I am just running web.application in this..
And I am getting same error of anything which is in requirements.txt., I tried: flask, redis, aiohttp.

Comment: try to replace the `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` with `RUN pip install aiohttp` and see if it's going to give you the same error. If it doesn't it might be that there's a problem with the requirements.txt file

Comment: Looks like your package aiohttp has a standing issue [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=ERROR%3A+No+matching+distribution+found+for+aiohttp&oq=ERROR%3A+No+matching+distribution+found+for+aiohttp&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.595j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Try updating your python to 3.6 if you are using a lesser version;  that seems to resolve it.

Comment: @Stefano Yes, tried using RUN pip install aiohttp
But still same issue is there.

Comment: @ khari-sing I am using python 3.6 only...

Comment: Could you change `python:3.6` to `python:3.6-slim-buster` and try again?